# Where can I find icons for all browsers

Tags: cross-browser, icon

I need to create a "works on all major browsers" graphics for a web application, where can I find free or cheap images of browser icons from all the major browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari)?

Alternatively, is there a (again, free or cheap) ready made "works on all browsers" image I can use?

The images must be free or cheap for commercial use and preferably don't require attribution.

Answer (score 2):

I use [iconspedia](http://www.iconspedia.com/) to find the icons that I need.

Comment: Hey, great link.

Comment: If you have a disclaimer: All trademarks are owned by their respective owners or whatever, then usually you can use them - not sure about the distributing them. - At least with Iconspedia you define licenses in the search.

Answer (score 0):

[There are lots of free browser icons available for use.](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=free+browser+icons)

Comment: Actually not, look at the 5 first results of the Google search: #1 for personal use (I need it for a commercial project), #2 tons of icons - but no browser icons, #3 no browser icons, #4 same icons as #1 but with the license file removed, #5 iconpedia - has most browsers but no commercial use IE icon --- 90% of the browser icons you find on icon sites are the same "for personal use" set.

Comment: There are **a lot** of results. You don't have to look long to find a set that meets your criteria.